# How to copy value from one input to another with jquery using a link

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm using formidable forms plugin on a Wordpress site.
I have created a rather large and detailed form - and I was hoping to speed up the process of completing the form by my website users by allowing users to copy the value of one completed field into another field (if the data from the first filed is the same for the second field), instead of having to type out the second, same input.

Formidable Forms treats each field with a unique ID (in my example below, a user would complete field 104 and have the inputted value added to 105).

I'm trying to get the user to click on a link after the field (104) so that, once clicked, the value is copied into the field next to it (105)

So for example:
FIELD 1 -  "value of field_1"  >   click to copy  >  FIELD 2 - "value of field_1"

I've written the following script in jQuery and attached it to the html code of my form but it's missing the link and I can't get it to work...

(I've read everything here there is on this subject but I'm now at the stage, I seriously need help....)

```
    <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    // monitor field 1 for changes
    $('104').on('change', function() {
        var val1 = $(this).val();
        // assign the value to field 2
        $('105').val(val1);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would watch the changes on `keydown`, and decide to copy field values if at least 3 or more characters are entered, something like so:

```js
$('#field2').keydown(function(e) {
  var field1 = $('#field1').val();
  var similarFieldDetected = this.value.length >= 2 && field1.startsWith(this.value);

  $(this).next('a.copy').toggle(similarFieldDetected);
});

$('a.copy').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var field1 = $('#field1').val();

  $('#field2')
    .val(field1)
    .focus()
    .next('a.copy')
    .hide();
});
```

```css
html, body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.materialdesignicons.com/3.3.92/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-10">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="field1">Address 1:</label>
    <input id="field1" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your address" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="field2">Address 2:</label>
    <input id="field2" class="form-control" placeholder="Try typing out exactly the same value as Address 1" />
    <a class="copy form-text" href="#" style="display:none;">
      <small><i class="mdi mdi-content-copy"></i> Copy Address #1</small>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```